# How to get line number and source file from rejected Promises using onunhandledrejection

Tags: javascript, error-handling, promise

I was wondering if it's possible to get the line number and source file from rejected promises using `window.onunhandledrejection`, similar to the metadata you can get with  with `window.onerror`:

```
window.onerror = function (event, source, lineno, colno, error) {
  console.log('error occurred', { event, source, lineno, colno, error });
};
```

I tried inspecting the `event` parameter you get in the `onunhandledrejection` callback but couldn't find any relevant metadata.

[image]

My gut tells me there must be a way to get the source file and line number given that the dev console is printing out the source file and line number where the promise was rejected (e.g. `test.html:44`).